# insert selected row and static variable SQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo

is there any possible way to insert a static variable (say $static) AND insert a row selected from a database in the PDO statement?

I have been googling it all day and found nothing useful on the subject, its all on how to insert data that you've selected from the database but makes no mention of a PHP variable.

Answer (score 1):

there is absolutely no relation between PDO and class variables. you can bind any variable, all the same way.